# .pro file fails to read when switching to webassembly from desktop kit Qt Creator 6.6.0

Tags: qt, makefile, web-applications, webassembly, qmake

I just configured Qt for WebAssembly, but whenever I switch the kit to webassembly it fails to read the .pro file, and despite my efforts I just can't figure out why.

[[when I switch to webassembly kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcG4P.png)]
[[when I switch to desktop kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uP1w.png)]

[the issue that appears when I switch to WebAssembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvwKS.png)

I tried to tweak the kit settings in the project tab, as well to install a completely diffrent version of Qt (5.15.2) along with it's corresponding web assembly version, but it either did (seemingly) nothing or caused more problems. It is possible I screwed up the first (for Qt 6.6.0) WebAssembly installation, since it took me far more time than it should and I had to redo it at some point, but I don't see how would it stop the .pro file reading process.

Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT += webenginecore
QT += webenginewidgets


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

TRANSLATIONS += \
    html2_en_US.ts
CONFIG += lrelease
CONFIG += embed_translations

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Another thing is that the entire thing is running on a Gentoo Linux emulation on a chromebook (standard chromebook linux emulation). It didn't cause issues before, but who knows.

UPDATE: It appears switching to sigle-threaded version of WebAssembly shows the files, but they are greyed out and the error presists, as shown here:
[files greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izUMm.png)